# Deleting in SQL using multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-delete

Some background, I have a code column that is char(6). In this field, I have the values of 0,00,000,0000,000000,000000. It seems illogical but that's how it is. What i need to do is delete all rows that possess these code values. I know how to do it individually as such

```
delete from [dbo.table] where code='0'
delete from [dbo.table] where code='00'
```

and so on.

How does one do this one section of code instead of 6

Comment: It looks like there's an answer for all 3 options (`IN/OR`, `REGEXP`, and `CONVERT` to int), so I won't bother putting this into an answer. But keep in mind that if you have indexed this `code` column, only the IN/OR answer will take advantage of the index. CONVERT (or pretty well any function) will prevent the index from being referenced, as well REGEXP.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
delete from [dbo.table] where code='0'
                           or code='00'
                           or code='000'
```

etc. You get the idea.

There can be more efficient ways when the set of vales gets larger, but your 5 or 6 values is still quite a ways from that.

**Update**:

If your list grows long, or if your table is significantly larger than can reside in cache, you will likely see a significant performance gain by storing your selection values into an indexed temporary table and joining to it.

Comment: Consider `IN()` clause.

Comment: @Parfait. So something like this, "delete from [dbo.table] where in(code='0','00', and so on)?

Comment: @TimWilcox: `delete from [dbo.table] where code in ('0', '00', '000', '0000', '00000', '000000')`

Comment: @Parfait: "*IN clause considered harmful*". It is too easy to write, and oftern horrendously inefficient for long lists. If the list gets long, create a subquery (or even a  temporary table with an index) a VALUES clause and join to it.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Can you clarify if you're saying that `IN` is inappropriate to use in this case? As defined by the OP, the column is char(6), and they're looking for every combination of "0" (ie there will be six arguments passed to `IN`).  This seems like a good place to use `IN` - there are only a few arguments, and the SQL is shorter and easier to understand. The optimizer would convert `code IN ('0', '00', ...)` to `(code='0') OR (code='00') OR ...` on its own, anyway. I often use `in` for small queries like this in large procs, and I'd like to learn if I should be changing my habits.

Comment: @RToyota: Unless there has been a change in recent SQL Server versions, IN is always implemented as a sequential OR; thus five values means five passes of the data, possibly indexed. If NOT indexed, that is as many complete table scans as values. That's fine for short lists, but for larger lists JOINING against an indexed temporary table will be much faster.

Comment: @RToyota: Even for large tables (ie, too large to reside in cache), it will likely be significantly faster to perform a single table scan joined to an in-memory table of values; again, using a join is more performant.  The optimizer automatically makes these optimizations to a JOIN plan, but has (at least traditionally) NOT done so for IN operations.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Thanks for going into detail with the explanation. I wasn't aware that multiple OR statements would result in multiple scans. And I can't find anything about that on Google, either. Do you happen to have a reference handy? Assuming that this is comparing an indexed column, I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around the idea that an optimizer can do a single scan for a join, but does multiples for OR. I'm also a bit confused about why you've posted an answer using multiple ORs, but don't want to just use IN, even though IN expands to multiple ORs.

Comment: @RToyota: Thank you for challenging me on that - I seem to be out of date. I was unable to replicate this (traditionally well known) behaviour on a SQL 2016 instance. The problem with having been around almost forever, is that not everything I know remains valid. ;-) Memory suggests that this optimization must be more recent than 2008 or 2008 R2.  The point to not using IN was to be **explicit** about the performance difficulties - but that no longer applies.

Answer (score 1):

It strongly depends on your DBMS, but I suggest to use regular expressions. For example, with MySQL you just need simple query like this:

```
delete from dbo.table where code regexp '(0+)'
```

For most of popular DBMS you can do the same, but syntax may be various

Comment: Why the downvote? Regex is a valid way to solve this problem.

Comment: I definitely did not downvote anybody. The answers from this question have been outstanding.

Comment: Not to sound naive but do I not have to specify a column is this regex item? I have other columns that could have a zero value in them.

Comment: @TimWilcox, my mistake, sorry. Of course, you need to specify column name, see the updated answer

Comment: What is the performance for this use of DOT NET code, with consequent context switching, on a large table? Seems like a table scan is needed since the criteria is a non_SARG, with two martialling context-switches  ***for every row***. Looks really sucky to me.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now, but the following should work:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.table WHERE CONVERT(int, code) = 0
```

edit- Just thought of another way, that should be safer:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.table WHERE LEN(code) > 0 AND LEFT(code + '0000000000', 10) = '0000000000'
```

Comment: I will test it out in just a few.

Comment: MySQL, for example, returns 0 when you try to cast e.g. '0a0', so I think this is potentially dangerous approach. Try `select cast('0a0' as unsigned)`. On the other engines the problem most likely occures too

Comment: This is a clever way to do it. @OlegRybalchenko brings up a good point, but on top of that, you should keep in mind that the code column might contain non-int values as well. Also, CONVERT() will prevent the use of an index on the code column.

Comment: @zambonee A small suggestion regarding your edit about padding: the values can be reduced to use 6 chars instead of 10 (the OP's column is char(6)). Also, if you only pad it with 5 zeros, you eliminate the need to do a LEN check (because if it is blank, and only padded with 5 zeros, it will not match the 6 zero string). This may be simpler: `DELETE FROM dbo.table WHERE LEFT(code + '00000', 6) = '000000'`